# CMYKJPEGImageReaderSpi not loading

Tags: image, tomcat, classpath, cmyk, meta-inf

I was having an issue of reading CMYK JPEG images , and have used below url as reference for solving the issue.

http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2011/08/reading-cmyk-jpeg-images-with-java-imageio/

I have given the configuration org.monte.media.jpeg.CMYKJPEGImageReaderSpi in the file javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi under path /META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.

This works perfectly inside eclipse and the image reader is loaded successfully.

This file is not loading when deployed , i can find the folder and the file in the generated war file in my desired jar file inside lib folder, i guess i need to add it to java classpath.

Please help me to add to classpath or if there is any other issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this file as a static resource to your build lifecycle.

For *Ant* or *Gradle* you just need to write a simple copy task ([Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), [Gradle task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html)), for *Maven* you can use [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).

After that your file should appears in your app package.

Comment: I added entry in pom.xml

    <resources>
    <resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
    <include>META-    INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi</include>
    </includes>
    </resource>
    </resources>

Same error i got , the reader is not loading. Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: First of all remove extra space from `<include>META- INF/services...` After that check if resource appears in app package. If it's not then recheck your pom configuration for *Maven Resources plugin*. In addition to your extra resource you need to specify phase and goal when resources will be processed (see link above).